# Implementing your own malloc/free with mmap and munmap

Tags: c, memory-management, mmap

I have implemented by own **malloc** and **free** using **mmap**. Now since unlike **free**, **munmap** also takes length as parameter, therefore I put length as an additional information in the mapped memory.

The code for my **malloc** and **free** is shown below. I want to ask, if this code is good or am I still missing anything or doing something in a wrong way.

```
void * malloc ( size_t size )
{
    int *plen;
    int len = size + sizeof( size ); // Add sizeof( size ) for holding length.
    
    plen = mmap( 0, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0 );
    
    *plen = len;                     // First 4 bytes contain length.
    return (void*)(&plen[1]);        // Memory that is after length variable.
}

void free ( void * ptr )
{
    int *plen = (int*)ptr;
    int len;
    
    plen--;                          // Reach top of memory
    len = *plen;                     // Read length
    
    munmap( (void*)plen, len );
}
```

Comment: I would suggest making a basic test program that runs these a bunch of times with a bunch of different parameters and running it through Valgrind to see if any issues pop up.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Paul: still having trouble navigating all the different sub forums, from the one you mention to, say, SO's ubuntu forum. Could you kindly advise how/where to get a list of them?

Comment: @gnometorule: click on the StackExchange word right at the top of the page on the left - this will pop up a window - then click on "All Sites"

Answer (score 18):

Some observations:

- You assume that `int` and `size_t` have the same size. If you want to store a `size_t` value at the head of the allocation, then why don't you just do that? Why introduce `int`?
- This will very likely be quite inefficient, both in terms of memory usage and speed. There is significant overhead to `mmap()`, and typically allocations cannot be smaller than a "page". Most real allocators try to avoid calling OS-level functionality on every `malloc()`, in various ways.
- If `mmap()` fails, it will return `MAP_FAILED`, and so should `malloc()`. Thus, you need to test for that *before* de-referencing the pointer returned by `mmap()`.
- Calling `free(NULL)` should be a valid thing to do; with your implementation it will very likely cause a crash since you don't `NULL`-check the argument before assuming it's valid.

Comment: Very often, in many C programs, the `malloc`-ed size is much smaller than a page, so you have to keep several memory chunks in one (or several consecutive) pages. For instance when you are `strdup`-ing some name or human language word, the typical size is one or a few dozen bytes, but the typical page size is 4Kbytes! You also have to accept large `malloc` requests and handle them specially.

Comment: @Basile: That said, my current PC has 4096 times as much memory as my first PC allowed to some programs. So it's not out of the question that toy programs could run with this allocator, just don't try linking Firefox against it. What you *really* want, though, is *two* pages per paltry dozen-byte allocation, aka "guard page after" ;-)

Comment: Yes, but the current software on your PC is using perhaps five thousand more memory than what was used before. RAM is like disk space, it tends to be full....

Comment: @Basile: My RAM is not full: current physical memory usage is 50%, most of which can be paged out to the swap file. I say again, the size of program that can be run on my PC with this absurd allocator is roughly comparable to the size of program that could be run in conventional memory on my first PC. That doesn't make this a *good* allocator, just one that's better than completely useless.

Comment: @Basile: indeed, assuming you only hook user calls to `malloc` and not any hidden allocation that goes on in the standard libraries, your `malloc` conforms to the letter if not the spirit of the standard. MetallicPriest's is much more useful, though, since his does support programs with modest memory requirements (say, a few tens of thousand blocks allocated at any one time).

Comment: @unwind: `mmap` will return `MAP_FAILED` when it fails rather than `NULL`.

Comment: @rpetrich D'oh! Thanks, that was sloppy of me. Fixed.

Answer (score 10):

You should, at least.

- Check if `mmap` fails
- store a `size_t` for the size, not an `int`. They might be different.
- return suitable aligned memory, the memory here seems to be 4 byte aligned (as you add an `int`, presumably 4 bytes, to the page aligned data from mmap. This means storing values that need larger alignment in the returned memory, e.g. a double incurs a performance penalty, or outright crashes on some architectures.
- Handle `NULL` being passed to free (it's supposed to be a no-op)

For a malloc implementation, i'd also expect it to at least have rudimentary debugging support, e.g. try to detect double frees, try to detect free'ing invalid pointers, list memory not free'd etc.

Keep in mind your malloc implementation here can be extremely wasteful. If you malloc 10 bytes , you'll end up allocating 1 page (4096 bytes), that all have to be mapped to physical memory, with the remaining 4082 bytes being unused.

Answer (score 3):

Read also [c malloc on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) and study carefully some real malloc implementations like [Doug Lea's malloc](ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c). There is a lot of litterature on the subject, e.g. [by Wolfram Gloger](http://www.dent.med.uni-muenchen.de/~wmglo/malloc-slides.html) and many many others.

@MetallicPriest: you really should explain much much more what you are doing (I am not very optimistic for your work, but you'll probably learn a big lot!)

Comment: There's a "Forbidden" error while accessing Wolfram Gloger's link.Can you link to some open access article, if available?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call mmap each time you call your custom malloc. As stated before there is a huge overhead doing this.

You should create a large sized shared memory (4K for example) and your malloc function will only have to return pointers in the range of the memory you alocated.

Then if you get short on memory you create an other 4k of shared memory.

You'll just have to count how much space you use and keep track of your references and that way freeing memory is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

And you also should use `-1` instead of `0` as the fd argument of mmap.

```
mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)
```

> MAP_ANONYMOUS
>
> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are  initialized  to  zero. The fd and offset arguments are ignored; however, some implementations require fd to be -1 if MAP_ANONYMOUS (or MAP_ANON) is specified, and portable  applications  should  ensure  this.   The  use  of  MAP_ANONYMOUS  in conjunction with MAP_SHARED is supported on Linux only since kernel 2.4.